# Using GSON, How to convert JSON to Java when some keys have special character

Tags: java, json, gson

An external API gives me a JSON object as follows:

```
{
    "@date": "1407436242",
    "@duration": "2411",
    "Entry": {
        "@position": "3",
        "@playerName": "fred"
    }
}
```

As you can see, all keys start with an @ sign, except for one, which is a nested object. We are using GSON for parsing JSON, and I'm trying to do this as simply as possible, without manually converting each key to a valid Java field name.

I'm currently trying with this code:

```
MyObject response = gson.fromJson(stringInput, MyObject.class);
```

and this matches no fields except TournamentEntry.

I tried added a gson field naming strategy, but this seems to be an all-or-nothing approach, and can't handle that some keys have an "@" sign and some don't.

How can I tell GSON to drop the "@" signs when converting to Java field names, while still handling the nested objects which don't have the @ sign?

Comment: you can try to remove all the @ using `jsonString.replaceAll("\\@","")`

Comment: You can use any of a dozen different JSON kits to produce the corresponding nested Map objects.

Comment: @SparkOn That's the current approach I'm using...but there could be @ signs inside some value fields...so that's not ideal.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm hoping to do it specifically with GSON so as not to change the current JSON library we are using in our project.

Answer (score 4):

Gson provides the [SerializedName](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation which should allow for the use of those funky json identifiers.  This would make your classes look as such:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.Date;

public class Event {

  @SerializedName("@date")
  private Date date;

  @SerializedName("@duration")
  private long duration;

  @SerializedName("Entry")
  private Entry entry;

}
```

and

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Entry {

  @SerializedName("@position")
  private int position;

  @SerializedName("@playerName")
  private String playerName;  

}
```

The great thing about @SerializedName is that it works on a per-field basis, so you only need to annotate when required.

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing your JSON into a `JsonElement` first using GSON's [`JsonParser`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html), and then preprocessing that to remove any keys that begin with @ and replace it with the actual key. After that, you can call `gson.fromJson` with the modified `JsonElement` instead of the JSON String.

Below is an example of how to do this. It checks whether the element is a JSON object, and if so replaces all keys that begin with @. All values are then recursively put through the same method (so that you also replace e.g. @position in your example).

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String json = "{\n"
            + "    \"@date\": \"1407436242\",\n"
            + "    \"@duration\": \"2411\",\n"
            + "    \"Entry\": {\n"
            + "        \"@position\": \"3\",\n"
            + "        \"@playerName\": \"fred\"\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "}";

    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(json);

    // Modify the JsonElement, replacing any keys beginning with @
    removeAtSymbolsInKeys(jsonElement);

    MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, MyObject.class);
    System.out.println(myObject);
}

private static void removeAtSymbolsInKeys(JsonElement jsonElement) {
    if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = new HashSet<>(jsonObject.entrySet()); // Make a copy so we can modify JsonObject

        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            JsonElement value = entry.getValue();

            if (key.startsWith("@")) {
                String newKey = key.replaceFirst("@", "");
                jsonObject.add(newKey, value);
                jsonObject.remove(key);
            }

            // Replace the keys of any values that are objects
            removeAtSymbolsInKeys(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the recursive method will throw a StackOverflowError if your JSON is extremely nested, but this should hopefully never be the case.

Comment: You know, it would be simpler and more straight-forward to just write a constructor that accepts a Map.

Comment: @HotLicks Perhaps, but the original question asked for a solution "without manually converting each key to a valid Java field name".